# Discover the beginning of the conversation

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm still missing out on how to find out where the start of my conversation is since I want to write the user to my database and would need that GUID of it.

My middleware

```
 bot.use({

    // User sends bot
    receive: (event, next) => {

        if (event.type == 'message' || event.type == 'conversationupdate') {
            api.post.receive(event)
        }

        next()
    },

    // Bot sends user
    send: (event, next) => {

        if (event.type == 'message') {
            api.post.send(event)
        }

        next()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage [`conversationUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-handle-conversation-events#greet-a-user-on-conversation-join) event, where should be the start of conversations.

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', (message) => {
    if (message.membersAdded && message.membersAdded.length > 0) {
        //store user info 
        console.log(message.membersAdded)
    }
})
```

And the user info are stored in `message.membersAdded`

Comment: To add to this, some channels do not leverage the conversation update for this.  some use the `contactRelationUpdate`  Which can be found on the same page of documentation Gary linked.  This may help depending on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Every conversation history I want to send to my API and write to the database, however before I need the user information (id, name) to be able to link the messages to the user. So that's why I'm looking where I start the conversation so I can get the user's data. However I will use several channels, messenger, skype, web, among others.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, you want to get information from the user **before** the conversation starts?  How do you plan to get that information if the conversation hasn't started?

Comment: Maybe I'm still lost in the flow. But when the user sends the first message or click on "get started" (messenger) I will be able to access the id and name it right? Taking into consideration that the 'conversationUpdate' does not work in messenger, how could I get this data in the first conversation?

Comment: bot.use(builder.Middleware.firstRun({ version: 1.0, dialogId: 'firstRun' }))

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was this, do you find it viable in this way?

```
bot.use(builder.Middleware.firstRun({ version: 1.0, dialogId: 'firstRun' }))

bot.on('conversationUpdate', (session) => {
    if (session.membersAdded) {
        session.membersAdded.forEach((identity) => {
            if (identity.id === session.address.bot.id) {
                bot.beginDialog(session.address, 'firstRun')
            }
        })
    }
})


bot.dialog('firstRun', function (session) {    
    session.userData.firstRun = true
    // save user in my api
    session.send("Hello firstRun...")
}).triggerAction({
    onFindAction: function (context, callback) {
        // Only trigger if we've never seen user before
        if (!context.userData.firstRun) {
            // Return a score of 1.1 to ensure the first run dialog wins
            callback(null, 1.1)
        } else {
            callback(null, 0.0)
        }
    }
})
```